# .htaccess to exclude anything after root domain?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I have a subdomain like `abc.example.com` which has wordpress installed. Its `.htaccess` has this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

How do I make my root domain which is `example.com` not use wordpress because `example.com` is supposed to be running my node.js app?

Comment: Where is your application hosted?

Comment: @SrujanReddy digital ocean ubuntu server

Comment: You should run node and apache on different port numbers and use NGiNX to serve content accordingly.